# Remove first line of html source in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

My friends's Wordpress based website got infested with some malware. As a result if the website is opened through ssl, the malicious code adds  in the very first line of opened page a javasrcipt redirection:
`window.location.replace("https://malicious_address...")`.

I cannot find the way to locate and remove the malware but I thought i could circumvent it. If somewhere at at the beginning of the WP loading sequence i could place `ob_start()' and load everything into a buffer  and at the  very end just output everything except the redirection, this would pretty much solve the problem. Would you know where I should place that? I don't know WP almost at all and my php skills are also very basic, just trying to help a friend. Could you guys advise?

Comment: I would look in theme, or plugins

Answer (score 1):

I would look in theme, or plugins

if they are clean, dump database and look there too. If clean

download clean copy of wordpress and replace with old one OR rename old copy and put new one, add wp-config from old copy and add theme/plugins/uploads to new one.